# Oracle's date and time without daylight savings via JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timezone, dst

Issuing the following SQL generates different results thru PL/SQL, ODBC and JDBC:

```
select sysdate from dual
```

When running it on PL/SQL or ODBC, the date and time is correct. On JDBC it comes with an hour less. It seems that it is not considering daylight savings.

For example, on PL/SQL the result is `2012-11-05 16:53:53.0` and on JDBC it is `2012-11-05 15:53:53.0`.

It happens only on some databases. Changing the database timezone (`select dbtimezone from dual`) doesn't seems to affect the results.

The command is executing on Brazil. Raw GMT offset is -03:00, current offset is -02:00 because of daylight savings.

The timezone database of the client JVM is up-to-date.

To diagnose the "wrong" result from database, just print the result:

```
((OracleResultSet) statement.executeQuery("select sysdate from dual")).getTIMESTAMP(1).toString();
```

Oracle's `TIMESTAMP` `toString` method do not rely on timezone information. The JVM's timezone may only affect the result before the creation of the `TIMESTAMP`, i.e. while reading from the network and transforming it into a representation in Java.

Tests on changing both client and database server time configuration:

- `SYSDATE` always return the date/time resolved in the database server, the client JVM's `user.timezone` option and client's machine time configuration do not matter.
- On the other hand, getting `SYSTIMESTAMP` is resolved using both timezone informations: looks like it gets the date and time from server in UTC and then apply the timezone in the client to get a local date and time.

Client is running Windows, server is running Linux.

To get things more weird, issuing a `TO_CHAR` yield the wrong result too:

```
select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

- Directly on Oracle: `06/11/2012, 10:38:49`
- On Java: `06/11/2012 09:38:49`

Oracle servers:

```
[root@oracle1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="America/Sao_Paulo"
UTC=false
ARC=false
[root@oracle1 ~]# echo $TZ

[root@oracle1 ~]# date
Tue Nov 13 14:58:38 BRST 2012
[root@oracle1 ~]#


[root@oracle2 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="America/Sao_Paulo"
UTC=false
ARC=false
[root@oracle2 ~]# echo $TZ

[root@oracle2 ~]#  date
Tue Nov 13 14:59:58 BRST 2012
[root@oracle2 ~]#
```

Any thoughts? What info or configuration should I collect from the database to diagnose and solve this problem?

Comment: You might have older timezone database. Make sure timezone database is same on all databases. see this if helps http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/timezones-137583.html

Comment: Nambari, which timezone database should I update? Java client issuing the SQL is already updated.

Comment: "On JDBC it comes with an hour less. It seems that it is not considering daylight savings" means, your jvm timezone need to be updated.

Comment: As I said on previous comment, the client JVM issuing the SQL is already updated. JVM's time is fine. I did dig on Oracle's source code and it seems to get the raw date directly from the database, not using the timezone from the JVM.

Comment: `getdbdatetime` is not a predefined function in Oracle.  I'm assuming it is a function that you created.  Can you post the definition of that function?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Anyway, `sysdate` is returning the "wrong" result. Edited the question removing `getdbdatetime`.

Comment: @ThiagoNegri: How are you diagnosing this "wrong" result, exactly?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Checking the oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP returned. The internal representation is an array of bytes representing date and time, with no timezone information.

Comment: @ThiagoNegri: And how are you fetching it? For example, did you try calling `getTimestamp()`? That sounds like the obvious approach...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Casting the `ResultSet` to `OracleResultSet` and using `getTIMESTAMP`. Like this: `((OracleResultSet)stmt.executeQuery("select sysdate from dual")).getTIMESTAMP(1).toString();`.

Comment: @ThiagoNegri: Right - you're still using `toString()` though. I would frankly not trust that output - I'd look at the results of `timestampValue`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Oracle's `TIMESTAMP` `toString` method does not uses JVM timezone information. Changing `user.timezone` do not change it's result.

Comment: @ThiagoNegri: I dare say it doesn't, but I'm still not comfortable with blindly trusting *any* string representation. Anyway, I don't think this is getting anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, selecting an oracle `DATE` into a Java `Date` is inherently problematic. That's because they are fundamentally different. An Oracle `DATE` is the combination of year, month, day, hours, minute, seconds, without any timezone information, so it could be any timezone, with or without daylight saving - Oracle doesn't know, since that information isn't included in the `DATE`.

On the other hand, a Java Date basically is the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC.

When an Oracle `DATE` goes into a Java `Date`, the JDBC driver can only guess which timezone to apply. The results are rather unpredictable, especially when the data in the database use another timezone than the user.

Comment: I'm using Oracle's `TIMESTAMP` type directly. Not stretching it into a Java `Date`.

Comment: On the Oracle side, `SYSDATE` delivers a `DATE`, not a `TIMESTAMP`. In Java, `java.sql.Timestamp` *is* a `Date`. Therefore, by selecting `SYSDATE` into a `Timestamp`, you have to expect all the problems I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm not using `java.sql.Timestamp`. I'm using `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

Java Dates don't have timezones until you format them.

A java date is internally stored as a long - the number of milliseconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970, midnight UTC.

Look at the java Date's time, along with it's reported time zone (however you format it), and you'll probably see that it is equivalent to the time in the database.

You most likely have a problem with formatting the date - using a timezone other than the one that you expect. I'm guessing that you are not specifying the time zone (using the default one) when formatting, or simply using Date's toString() method.

If you use the Calendar (calendar.setTime(date)), you can combine the 'epoch time' with a specific time zone, or if it works for you, use the default time zone. You can also query a Calendar for it's timezone, and if the default one is incorrect, then you will indeed need to investigate whether either the computer itself is set to the wrong timezone, or whether something is amiss with the java timezone database on that computer.

Comment: There are no issues with Java's timezone handling. The date returned from the database, and not from JVM is "wrong". If I get the date from SYSDATE and re-insert it, without touching or printing it, the date inserted is incorrect. It only happens in some databases. The same application is behaving in different ways.

Comment: "Look at the java Date's time, along with it's reported time zone (however you format it), and you'll probably see that it is equivalent to the time in the database." - I don't think this is right. If your DB and application are in different timezones, the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC is calculated incorrectly.

Comment: @CodeClimber: it shouldn't be. In most(probably not all) databases, as in Java, the 'base' or 'epoch' is in UTC, and the number of millis since UTC is also obviously calculated in UTC. Timezone should only come into play when formatting for display. I don't doubt that Thiago is having a problem, but I believe that it's a combination of an incomplete understanding of how Java dates work (displaying a formatted date, intentionally, or through Date.toString, either directly or indirectly, instead of displaying the millis) and possibly using an Oracle column type that introduces time zone.

Answer (score 0):

"Java Dates don't have timezones until you format them." Wrong, it is defined as UTC.
The original answer by ammoQ is correct.  Database Date columns don't have timezone, although it may be stored as milliseconds since midnight 1 Jan 1970, it isn't defined as UTC, it is any timezone you like (ie same local time regardless of timezone).

In particular, JDBC uses the JVM's default timezone when converting to java Date in UTC.  So if the database stores 1/1/2014 02:00, and your JVM is "America/Chicago" then you get a java Date equivalent to 1/1/2014 02:00 CST.  If your JVM is "America/New_York" then you get a java Date equivalent to 1/1/2014 02:00 EST.  This is a very different moment in time, an hour (3600000 milliseconds) differnt, which happens to be equivalent to 1/1/2014 01:00 CST, not 02:00 CST.

However the biggest issue with using the JVM's timezone occurs every year during the "overlap hour" if that timezone honors Daylight Saving Time.  The database will say 01:30 on the fall-back Sunday (in US timezones), but which 01:30 is it, the first in Daylight Time or the second after the switch back to Standard Time?  The JDBC/JVM has to arbitrarily choose between these two moments in time.  As I recall, I think most JVMs will always use Standard Time (the second 01:30).  Although during the Spring jump to Daylight Saving Time, a time of 02:30 technically does not exist, but I think most JVMs will assume 03:30 after the spring-forward to Daylight time.

Answer (score 0):

Try vm parameter

```
-Duser.timezone=GMT-2
```

or

```
-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo
```

Java has its own timezone settings and it may affect transfer of Date objects.