# Optimize JDBC Oracle query to give consistent results across time zones and day light saving

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timezone

At our company Java web applications (Web sphere is the app server) run in windows boxes located in Arizona (MST). Our oracle database is in Chicago (CST). The following query is consistent all the times except between 11 PM and 12 AM MST. When I say consistent what I mean is if I run the query against the database via SQLDeveloper and the JDBC Query via java program will give the same result.

```
select extract(day from(systimestamp - to_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))) as systimestamp2 from dual;
```

**Sample failure case as example:**
When I run the above query at 11 PM MST on 12th July 2016 the result from the Java program is `16994` and the result from the sql developer is `16995`. Other than this time interval of 1 hour between 11 PM MST and 12 AM MST they are equal. So it is working as expected before 11 PM MST and after 12 AM MST.

I have tried various variants of query as shown below and none of them worked.

```
select extract(day from(sys_extract_utc(current_timestamp) - sys_extract_utc(to_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))) as systimestamp2 from dual;

select extract(day from(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) - sys_extract_utc(to_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))) as systimestamp2 from dual;
```

I found similar threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238698/oracles-date-and-time-without-daylight-savings-via-jdbc) through which I got to know that the fate of the JDBC query depends on the timezone of the JVM. So when I changed the JVM timezone to MDT or UTC the problem is solved. But this is not acceptable workaround at our company since it needs regression testing and budget.

So what I am looking for is **Is there way to modify the query to make it consistent across time zones and day light savings**.

PS: Just thought of including my complete query so that it might be clear what I am trying to achieve

```
select extract(day from(systimestamp - to_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))) * 86400000 + to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp), 'SSSSSFF3')) as systimestamp2 from dual;
```

Adding my Java Code to demonstrate the sql query execution via Java

```
public long getSystemTimestampInMilliSeconds() {
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            String sql = "select extract(day from(systimestamp - to_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))) * 86400000 + to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp), 'SSSSSFF3')) as systimestamp2 from dual";
            cs = conn.prepareCall(sql);
            rs = cs.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getLong(1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogFacility.logError( LogFacility.LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Exception in UtilityStore.getSystemTimestampInMilliSeconds " + e.getMessage() );
        } finally {
            close(rs, cs, conn);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have tagged the question with java and jdbc; could you share the Java code you're using for `Statement` and `ResultSet` handling? This would be important because the problem is most likely in the way `DATE` parameters are being passed from the Java client to Oracle.

Comment: @ Mick Mnemonic - I have shared my Java code. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Ok, so you're not passing any (date) parameters into the query?

Comment: @ Mick Mnemonic - No. I don't have any date parameters. I am guessing that the systimestamp in the first part of the query is the one causing problems. Its assuming the time zone of JVM.

Comment: `systimestamp` and `sysdate` correspond to database time and don't know anything about the time zones of possible clients. Perhaps the problem is with the `to_timestamp` conversion and the NLS parameters it implicitly uses.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this kind of comportment. We don't find a good the solution, we modify the program and now I change job. In that case there is issue between ODBC and JDBC. It is the oracle driver which have to make time conversion between boxes. And SQLDeveloper use also JDBC driver so I don't know for you.

But maybe the documentation will help you: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#CBBEEAFB

Another way is to force / check the jvm timezone:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST");
TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
```

Or maybe that because "CST" is deprecated (javadoc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the whole number of days since Jan 1, 1970, you don't need to use timestamps at all or look at time zones.  Just use simple date arithmetic

```
select trunc(sysdate) - date '1970-01-01'
  from dual
```

This will get the current date and time from the database server's operating system in whatever time zone that is.  There are no client settings that would impact this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right in a way that I am after the number of days from Jan 1, 1970 and I would like to use those days to multiply it with 86400000 to convert it to milli seconds. I added my complete query and what I am trying to achieve is to get the time from Jan 1 1970 till now in milli sec.

Comment: Also I think if I run trunc(sysdate) via JDBC I think I will still go off by one day between the times I mentioned.

Comment: @AdityaSarma - Since `sysdate` is based solely on the time reported by the operating system that the database is running on, the result will be the same regardless of the client.  It will be consistent.  Perhaps you mean to say that the result is not exactly what you want (if so, can you be a bit more specific about what you want).  Based on the substantial change you made, I'm now guessing that you want the number of milliseconds between the current time in UTC and Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I think you have summarized it more appropriately. Yes I am looking for the number of milliseconds between current time in UTC and Jan 1, 1970 and the result should be independent of client.